# How to loop over dataset to convert string to float, replace and split into list without using any library except Numpy?

Tags: python-3.x

How to loop over dataset to convert string to float, replace and split into list without using any library except Numpy in python?

```
for y in dataset:
y.replace("class-1\n", "1")
```

here instances of dataste

```
['5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,class-1\n', '4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,class-1\n', '4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,class-2\n', '4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,class-2\n', '5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,class-3\n']
```

So I would to replace class-1, class-2 and class-3 in one loop to 1,2 and 3 respectively?
converting string to float and split (",").

Comment: [fromregex](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html) is your friend here